# Combining objects from memory to other objects

Tags: java, memory

I'm looking for a way in Java to use only one object with multiple references instead of multi objects with only one reference.

I have a client server application where the client is locally saving data that it need to show to the users. But when the client has two screens open it can contain multiple objects from the server. And for memory it's better to detect this and change the reference to the first object.

For example:
Server send list of A objects with every A object that have a link to object B;

```
class B {}

class A
{
    private B varB;
}
```

After a moment the client asks for other data to feed another screen.

```
class C
{
    private B varB;
}
```

So objects B are twice in the clients memory. Is there a way to check in memory for the twice the same objects and change the references to only one object and discard the other from the memory?

Comment: So you have a client-server application where the clients run always in the same VM?

Comment: Its the same client that can have multiple windows open. So it runs in the same VM

Comment: "multi objects with only one reference." is not possible. A reference refers to only one and one object.

Comment: "Server send list of A objects with every A object that have a link to object B;" - how exactly? Or maybe server sends json/xml and you create these objects when you receive a response?

Comment: It really looks like a cache problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every request made to the server, you will have to look what objects came that request; if the object wasn't loaded before, store it into a cache; if it was already loaded before, replace it with the copy in the cache. The level of sifficulty of such an implementation will depend on how your program is structured.